# Do something if an image is not loaded (jquery)

Tags: jquery, image, load, onload

I'm looking to fade in the background image when a visitor arrives at the site but not when they've already got that image in their cache. Something along the lines of this:

1. Check if a background image is already in the cache.
2. If it is then show it.
3. If it isn't then hide it and when it loads, fade it in.

Using jQuery I can hide it and then fade it in when it loads:

```
$("#bkg img").hide();

$('#bkg img').load(function() {  
 $(this).fadeIn();  
});
```

But how do I make this conditional so it only happens if the image **isn't** already cached?

Everything I've found on forums triggers when an image finishes loading. How can I get it to trigger because it isn't loaded?

Thanks for any help,
Lernz

@Sima Based on code from [that other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446740/post-loading-check-if-an-image-is-in-the-browser-cache) I've made it as far as the following - but it doesn't seem to be having any effect. If you can see where I'm going wrong that'd be great:

```
var storage = window.localStorage;
if (!storage.cachedElements) {
 storage.cachedElements = "";
}

function logCache(source) {
 if (storage.cachedElements.indexOf(source, 0) < 0) {
  if (storage.cachedElements != "") 
  storage.cachedElements += ";";
        storage.cachedElements += source;
    }
}

function cached(source) {
    return (storage.cachedElements.indexOf(source, 0) >= 0);
}

var plImages;

//On DOM Ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    plImages = $("#fundo-1 img");

    //log cached images
    plImages.bind('load', function() {
        logCache($(this).attr("src"));
    });

    //display cached images

    plImages.each(function() {
     var source = $(this).attr("src")
     if (!cached(source)) {
        $(this).hide().fadeIn();
     }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
if(!$('#bkg img')[0].complete) {
    $('#bkg img').hide().load(function () {  
        $(this).fadeIn();  
    });
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLImageElement

Comment: Don't forget the to `.hide()` it  first (inside the `if`). :)

Comment: Yeah, *just* edited in. Dang it, long day and week, bring on Friday.

Comment: This isn't working for me. Thanks for the ref to .complete - I'm not familiar with that. Perhaps it doesn't work using the jQuery selector. How would I select using straight javascript?

Comment: `document.getElementById("bkg")` - but I'm pretty sure that's *not* the reason why it is not working.

Comment: Also, check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446740/post-loading-check-if-an-image-is-in-the-browser-cache as @Sima pointed out.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps it is working and I just wasn't testing it right. I changed the image to one I haven't used before and it behaved perfectly. I'd been testing by clearing the cache and reloading. Is there a better way of testing?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#bkg img").hide();    
var imgCount=$("#bkg img").length;
$('#bkg img').load(function(){
    if(!--imgCount){
        $('#bkg img').fadeIn();
            // your code after load
    } else {
        // your code onloading time
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that isn't as easy as it looks like, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446740/post-loading-check-if-an-image-is-in-the-browser-cache) should be a solution..

Comment: This is excellent but I'm having trouble getting my head round it. 

I want to ask whether $("#bkg img") exists within window.localStorage.cachedElements right? 

Let me give this a go...

Comment: Okay, I'm not really getting this. Does anyone have any further ideas?

Comment: Nope..You should first check the window.localStorage whether, there is your source string (according to linked solution) and then if it is not stored there , you should bind on the load event handler with fadeIn code, otherwise do nothing and let it display normally.
There isnt actually stored the image itself, there is only persistent info, whether the image has been loaded any time before (we pretend that if yes, it should be in cache..)