# how to check if an image was cached in js?

Tags: javascript, image, browser-cache

when I joined an interview , I was asked the question, I didn't know how to answer it .

do you know the key point of the question?

Answer (score 28):

Check if the `complete` attribute of the `Image` object is `true`:

```
function is_cached(src) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = src;

    return image.complete;
}
```

It seems to work (although it'll load the image if it isn't in the cache, which might not be what you want):

```
> is_cached('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3')
false
> is_cached('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3')
true
```

Comment: @JaredFarrish - I assume the wording you're looking for is "these test cases passed".  To me "it seems to work" implies not having gone out of his way to research the issue deeper than the question warranted.

Comment: This doesn't check the cache. It checks the DOM, you can verify this by opening two tabs, "checking" in one tab (false) "checking" again in same tab (true) and then going to the second tab and "checking" (false), even though it should be cached.

Comment: I'm finding that this solution doesn't always work even when operating in the same tab

Comment: If you reassign the image source to an empty string the image will not continue to load.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50111407/336929

Answer (score 6):

you could check like:

```
function is_cached(img_url){
    var imgEle = document.createElement("img");
    imgEle.src = img_url;
    return imgEle.complete || (imgEle.width+imgEle.height) > 0;
}

//and check, returns true or false depending on cached or not
is_cached("http://www.somesite.com/some_image.jpg");
```

Comment: Why is `|| (imgEle.width+imgEle.height) > 0;` necessary?