# How to change a link_to hover image in Rails 4 with an asset pipeline

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, hover, asset-pipeline, link-to

Note: This explanation is targeted for beginners.

I was facing the problem of not being able to change the image in a link_to when I hovered over the image.  Nothing I did in CSS seemed to solve the problem.  I present my solution to this problem below.

This is my link_to:

```
  <%= link_to image_tag('1487789814_back.png'),
      {controller: @controller_action_hash_from_params[:controller],
        action: @controller_action_hash_from_params[:action]},
        sql_text: @sql_text,
      :id => "ralph-back-button-black-img", :class => "ralph-fieldset-back-button" %>
```

1487789814_back.png is an ordinary png in app/assets/images.  It happens to be a black arrow pointing left.  Similarly, app/assets/images/1487789814_back_red.png (used below) is a red arrow pointing left.  I wanted the red arrow to appear when I hovered over a fieldset containing the black arrow.

---

### The source of the problem:

The link_to above generates/generated the following HTML:

```
<img src="https://localhost:3000/assets/1487789814_back-731afaae70e04062b25988079e4ef8ab4e6b523f4ac11ff7d142a9ff01e63455.png" alt="1487789814 back">
```

Note:
The file https://localhost:3000/assets/1487789814_back-731afa...3455.png" will not exist for you. It's a filename automatically generated by Rails

### Analysis:

The problem comes, in part, because (I believe) css cannot override HTML. That is, if you specify an attribute (e.g. width) in your HTML, you cannot override that in css. Similarly, (I believe) you cannot override the src="https: ..." in css.  Any attempt (I believe) to use :hover will fail.  To make this work, you'll need a bigger hammer: javascript or jquery.

---

### My solution:

Please note: I am not claiming this solution is the best solution or even a good solution. I am claiming it works in my Rails 4 environment.

If you are using the asset pipeline in Rails 4 (Rails 3? Rails 5?), your "friendly" image names (in my case 1487789814_back.png and 1487789814_back_red.png) will be converted by the asset pipeline system into names with a cryptographic hash appended. In other words, to get access to the red arrow image you need to know what name Rails assigned to your image.  It is beyond the cope of this little article to explain why Rails renames your image file; just know that it does.  (Of course, your original file will still be there with its original name.)

So somehow we must "map" the friendly name (e.g. "1487789814_back.png") to the name in the asset pipeline.

I accomplished this by creating a div with "display:none" css.

erb:

```
<%# This div has display:none.
    We do this in order to preload the images_path as well as create a "map"
      between the friendly name and the asset pipeline name
%>
<div class='ralph_preload'>
  <%= image_tag('1487789814_back.png',      options={class:'ralph_preload_class', id:'1487789814_back'}) %>
  <%= image_tag('1487789814_back_red.png',  options={class:'ralph_preload_class', id:'1487789814_back_red'}) %>
</div>
```

The erb above generated the following HTML:

```
<div class="ralph_preload">
  <img class="ralph_preload_class" id="1487789814_back" src="/assets/1487789814_back-731afaae70e04062b25988079e4ef8ab4e6b523f4ac11ff7d142a9ff01e63455.png" alt="1487789814 back">
  <img class="ralph_preload_class" id="1487789814_back_red" src="/assets/1487789814_back_red-bbd0f2e34f3401cc46d2e4e1e853d472d8c01c9a75f96d78032738bd01b2133b.png" alt="1487789814 back red">
</div>
```

The associated css is:

```
.ralph_preload {
  display: none;
}
```

I created some jQuery to change the black arrow to red when the user hovers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function get_precache_myStruct_array(outer_div_class){
    var myStruct_array = [];
    $('.'+outer_div_class).find(".ralph_preload_class").each(function(){
      var myStruct = {
        id: this.id,
        src: this.src
      };
      // myStruct_array.push(myStruct);
      myStruct_array[this.id] = myStruct;
    });
    return myStruct_array;
  }

  // See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352803/how-to-check-if-an-image-was-cached-in-js
  function is_cached(img_url){
    var imgEle = document.createElement("img");
    imgEle.src = img_url;
    return imgEle.complete || (imgEle.width+imgEle.height) > 0;
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
    var precache_myStruct_array = get_precache_myStruct_array("ralph_preload");
    $.each(precache_myStruct_array,
      function (index, value) {
        if (!is_cached(value.src)) {
          alert("Not cached!: " + value.src);
        };
    });

    <% if true %>
      $('#ralph-back-button-filedset').hover(function(){
        var precache_myStruct_array = get_precache_myStruct_array("ralph_preload");
        var imageID   = '1487789814_back_red';
        $('#ralph-back-button-black-img > img:nth-child(1)').attr("src", precache_myStruct_array[imageID].src);
      }, function(){
        var precache_myStruct_array = get_precache_myStruct_array("ralph_preload");
        var imageID = '1487789814_back';
        $('#ralph-back-button-black-img > img:nth-child(1)').attr("src", precache_myStruct_array[imageID].src);
      });
    <% end %>

  });
</script>
```

You might notice a "<% if true %>" / <% end %> block in the jQuery. Since the jQuery is "inlined" into the .erb file, the jQuery goes through erb processing.  By changing the true to false, it can make using browser debuggers easier to use.

---

### Conclusion:

I did a search on the web to find the answer to my problem. I found none that is, as the lawyers say, on point.

I am, of course, enthusiastically open to corrections and comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you put those images in your public folder, they will not get the extra hash added to the image name.

With that said, I ran a loop in my controller that got me all the "Rails" file names for my images and stored them somewhere I could access them easily.