# javascript search for the url in default browser cache

Tags: javascript

Please, write me a JavaScript function that search the Browser Cache:

```
function isInBrowserCache(url)
```

`url`:    address of a site with JSON response

`return`: true or false

Comment: did you try googling first ? what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please update on what you have tired and in case you are stuck at some point with an error, the community can help.

Comment: I have googled one full week. Almost no useful answers. Something that may make sense is below.

Answer (score 0):

One possible code that I found and improved is:

```js
var isInBrowserCache = function(url){
 window.caches.open('window-cache-v1').then(function(cache) {
  cache.match(url, {
   ignoreSearch: true,
   ignoreMethod: true,
   ignoreVary: true
  }).then(function(response) {
   if (response) {
    return true;
   } else {
    return false;
   }
  });
  });
}
```

This function always returns false, without the url in Browser Cache and with it.

Maybe the Browser Cache identification string is not "window-cache-v1".
Then there is a new JS cache. If you know the correct string, please write.

Answer (score 0):

WORKS FOR IMAGE URL 
Function that checks if an URL of an image is in Browser Cache 
@parameter: img_url  (URL of an image file) 
@return:    boolean  (true/false)

```
function isInBrowserCache(img_url) {
   var imgEle = document.createElement("img");
   imgEle.src = img_url;
   return imgEle.complete || (imgEle.width+imgEle.height) > 0;
}
```

DOES NOT WORK FOR JSON URL 
Function that checks if an URL of a JSON source is in Browser Cache 
@parameter: json_url  (URL of a JSON file) 
@return:    boolean   (true/false) 
    function isInBrowserCache(json_url) { 
       var jsonEle = document.createElement("json"); 
       jsonEle.src = json_url; 
       return jsonEle.complete; 
    }

The code above is created using the function 
 
is_cached(img_url):boolean 
from 
[how to check if an image was cached in js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352803/how-to-check-if-an-image-was-cached-in-js)