# Reliably checking against cached browser assets

Tags: javascript, caching, browser

Before outputting an image, we can test if it has been displayed before by generating an identical image element [and checking the `complete` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352803/how-to-check-if-an-image-was-cached-in-js/15352841#15352841) – this works nicely, but only while staying in [the current tab's DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352803/how-to-check-if-an-image-was-cached-in-js/15352841#comment48806206_15352841).

To test against assets in the browser's cache, some people suggest checking the `caches` object while others propose measuring against a loading duration threshold.

`await caches.keys()` is empty by default, but if same-domain images are added with `cache.add('/img/image.jpg')`, additional info like the original request timestamp on is available via `caches.match(…)`:

```js
let assetPath = '/favicon.ico';
caches.open('cachetest').then( cache =>
  cache.add( assetPath ).then( function(){
    caches.match( assetPath ).then( function ( asset ) {
      console.log( 'requested: ' + asset.headers.get('date') );
    } )
  } )
);
```

(test this in the console on multiple tabs of the same domain)

This is kind of a stopwatch approach in itself and a little unreliable.

- Did I miss out on a more robust way to check against cached assets?