# Javascript: How to check if image is already cached

Tags: javascript

I just started to learn a little bit of JavaScript and i wondered if there is a way to check if an image is already loaded to cache.

In my script im loading some random images from another webpage and display them.
When the same image will be displayed the second time, the script won't use the already loaded image, but instead load the same image again, so that there are two of them stored in my cache.

Now I want to check if the image is already stored in cache and if so, use the cached one instead of loading it again.

My code:

```
<script>
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    var index;

    //On Click create random 3digit number between 1 and 100
    document.getElementById('image').onclick = function(){
        var index = '' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 +1);

        while(index.length < 3) {
            index = '0' + index;
        }

        loadImages(index);
    };

    //Load the image with the created number
    function loadImages(id) {
        var src = 'someWebPage/' + id +'.png';            

        img.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('image').getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 300);
        }

        img.src = src;            
    } 
</script>
```

Picture of my cache:

[image]

As you can see `030.png` and `032.png` are twice in cache.

Hope you can give me some advice.

**EDIT:**
Just for anyone else that faces this problem, it actually isn´t one at all.
Chrome already did everything right, i only did not notice.
[image]
As you can see in the column `Size` the pictures were already loaded from my cache.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446740/post-loading-check-if-an-image-is-in-the-browser-cache

Comment: Browser handles this internally...you have no control over it and have no access to cache

Comment: @charlietfl Isn't it possible to access the cache using the [Resource Timing API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53650986/975097)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way caching (in this context) is handled is by the browser negotiating with the server using a set of headers to basically tell the server "I already have this version of this resource", to which the server can then respond "OK, that is still valid, no need to download anything new". So you shouldn't be concerned about the caching in the JavaScript side, but instead make sure you are setting the correct [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) headers on the server side. There are likely already questions/answers for your server/framework of choice on how to setup the caching there.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but is there any way to access the images directly from cache? So that i would not have to give this job to the browser, but instead i could just check if e.g `030.png` already exists in cache? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well there is the experimental [Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage), though you can't really rely on that for production use, as it is *experimental*. Other than that, to my knowledge there is no API to access the cache. You could do some custom caching layer yourself, but that seems overkill for something that is already natively handled by browsers, given correct server configuration.

Comment: Allright, Since this is not an actual program, but more some experementing by myself i'll just leave it to the browser, tanks for your help.